# Tigers lost to the dragons

Tags: algebra-precalculus

The sum of the score is 24. Both scores are even. The difference between the two scores is 6. What is the final score?

Comment: Try assigning symbols and forming equations. For example, $t, d$ be scores of Tigers and Dragons. Sum $= 24$ means $\_ + \_ = 24$, Difference $ = 6$ means $\_ - \_ = 6$ (Note that Tigers lost). Fill in the blanks and solve the equations.

Comment: What have you tried ?  At Math.SE, you have to show your effort so that the community can help you

Comment: I did a T chart but can't figure it out

Comment: @Nick What did your "T chart" look like?  Where in the process of solving this did you get stuck?  If you have a set of two equations with two unknowns, do you know how to solve the system?  (*Note: the pieces of information "the sum is 24" and "the difference is 6" contradicts the statement "both scores are even."  If you solve the system implied by the "sum" and "difference" sentences, you will get odd scores for both.  Is there a typo perhaps?*)

Answer (score 2):

$$D+T=24$$
$$D-T=6$$

Therefore,

$$D=T+6$$
$$\implies 2T=18$$
$$\implies T=9$$
$$\implies D=15$$

I'm sorry, but the scores are not even.